# range non-default parameter follows default one

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

Why does range allow a non-default parameter (`stop`) to *follow* a default parameter (`start`)?

Case in point:

```
>>> r = range(1, 2, 3)
>>> print(r.start, r.stop, r.step)
1 2 3
>>> r = range(10)
>>> print(r.start, r.stop, r.step)
0 10 1
```

Trying to emulate the signature is an obvious violation:

```
def my_range(start=0, stop, end=1):
    pass
```

I understand that the fact it is implemented in `C` probably allows for behavior that would be a violation in Pythonland.

I'm guessing this was done to make the API more user-friendly but, I didn't find any sources to back it up (The source code doesn't tell much and [PEP 457](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/#positional-only-parameter-semantics-in-current-python) only states how `range` is odd). Does anyone know why this was done?

Comment: check the docs: seems that `range` has 2 different signatures !! `class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
`

Comment: @JimFasarakisHiliard closed, but reopened. This isn't a dupe, I should read your questions better. Useful link anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637130/how-to-implement-python-method-with-signature-like-start-stop-step-i

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think I will because I'm not really looking to implement it myself :-).

Comment: too late, did that for ya :) now I cannot close the question again but I think I won't. I'd better come up with an answer.

Comment: found the source code, didn't help: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3f739f42be51/Objects/rangeobject.c (not a comment to explain why). My guess is as good as yours: it's useless to only allow start or step, and having to specify start and stop when doing a loop would be worse than a C loop. Maybe Raymond Hettinger or Alex Martelli could answer.

Comment: Glanced there for any comments but didn't find anything from a cursory glance.

Comment: I guess it's so obvious to them (not for us mere mortals)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the question is based on a wrong premise:

> I understand that the fact it is implemented in C probably allows for behavior that would be a violation in Pythonland.

It's implemented in C but the behaviour isn't a violation in "Pythonland". The signature in the documentation is just incorrect (not actually incorrect, it's an approximation of the "real signature" - that can be easily understood).

For example `range` doesn't even support named parameters - but according to the documentation it should:

```
>>> range(stop=10)
TypeError: range() does not take keyword arguments
```

So the implementation is more along the lines of:

```
class range(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        start, step = 0, 1
        if len(args) == 1:
            stop = args[0]
        elif len(args) == 2:
            start, stop = args
        elif len(args) == 3:
            start, stop, step = args
```

That's valid Python and (roughly) does what `range` internally does (the [actual implementation (CPython, Python 3.6.1)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/rangeobject.c#L71-L129) could be slightly different so don't take that class to seriously).

However a signature like `range(*args)` is probably not really helpful for users (especially new users that don't even know what `*args` means). Having a documentation that says `range` has 2 signatures: `range(stop)` and `range(start, stop[, step])` may not be (technically) accurate but it "explains" how the signature is interpreted.

---

As for the **why**: I don't have any creditable sources but I quickly scanned my code:

I use `range(stop)` much more often than `range(start, stop)` or `range(start, stop, step)`. So the one argument case was probably **special and common enough** to have a convenience for it. It would be pretty annoying to always write `range(0, stop)` all over the place.

Comment: I was going to answer (almost) the same thing (only shorter and not as weel documented as that one)

Comment: Practicality does beat purity. Thanks for the write-up; I'll look into this more thoroughly over the next days and get back if I find anything odd.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Did you find anything odd yet? xD

Comment: Sorry, @MSeifert, I had completely forgotten about this :-)

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard random.randrange() follows the same idea but it is implemented in Python and with the revealing comment "This code is a bit messy to make it fast...for the common case"-
 I think this reinforces that it is a practical choice https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/random.py#L173