# python: multiple constructors(__init__ signatures) in range class, how is it possible?

Tags: python, overloading, multiple-constructors, single-dispatch

I'm aware that [multiple constructors in python is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765482/multiple-constructors-the-pythonic-way).

However, I found the range class has two `__init__` signatures [from the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).

```
class range(stop)
class range(start, stop[, step])
```

At first I thought it's implemented like this
`def __init__(stop, start=None, step=None)` But this will change the order of parameters for `start` and `stop`

So I check the python source code and the range class has the completely different methods here:

```
    def __init__(self, stop): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        pass

    @staticmethod # known case of __new__
    def __new__(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
        """ Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature. """
        pass
```

Can anyone explain how it works? Can we do the same in our object class?

Is it something to do with [single-dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482/python-function-overloading)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999181/range-non-default-parameter-follows-default-one (ran out of close votes, so this is just a comment).

Comment: Don't confuse overloading a single constructor *name* with having multiple constructors. A class method is essentially an alternate constructor. (`__init__` is *not* a constructor; it's an initializer. It receives as its first argument an already-constructed object.)

Comment: @MSeifert  I think that’s the answer! Thank you very much !

Comment: @chepner got you. Thank you